# Drawing shapes with React-Native ART

Tags: react-native, d3.js

I have 2 questions about drawing shapes with React-Native ART.

The React-Native ART library contains a `Path` Component which can be used like this

```
import { ART } from "react-native";
const { Path } = ART;

var path = new Path();
path.lineTo(100, 0);
path.close();
console.log(path)
```

The output of this is `Array [2, 100, 0, 1, ]`

This array / path can be supplied to React-Native ART's `Shape` like this

```
<Shape
d={path}
stroke="#000"
strokeWidth={1}
/>
```

In this case it will draw a horizontal line.

Another popular javascript library for generating paths is d3-shape. The output from a typical `d3.shape.line()` looks something like `M0,80L100,100L200,30L300,50L400,40L500,80`. This string could also be supplied to React Native Shape to draw something.

My 2 questions are as follows:

1) How is it that you can supply both formats to `Shape`

2) Can I convert the array format from ART's Path, to the string format as in d3. I have need for this particular ability. Also can I convert from the d3 format to the ART format?

I would love some insights into this topic and any input at all is much appreciated.

Many thanks.